# Series of sci-fi short stories for kids/ young adults

Tags: story-identification, books

I remember reading back in primary school a series of short stories, one was about a brother and a sister who go through a traumatic alien abduction, leading to the brother want to return to the aliens, who only want his sister, so she is kidnapped at the end.

Another is an infestation of flesh eating insects who cannot be culled. I can't remember this one as well as the first. They were illustrated in black and white, does anyone have an idea what series I read? Thanks!

Comment: How many years ago did you read these? Were these two stories in the same volume, or same series of volumes? If not, what is the connection between them? Try to read https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info or https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/4918 to give hints about other information you can supply to help us find the right book.

Comment: This was around 2011/12, and they were both part of the same series, though it was one story per book, if that helps